# ZF2 routing ignores namespace

Tags: php, routes, namespaces, zend-framework2

I am having an issue with zf2 routing. I am using skeleton example https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php, but when I tying to access `http://localhost/admin/` or `http://localhost/admin/answers` I am getting 404 with message:

```
A 404 error occurred

Page not found.

The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
Index(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Index)
No Exception available
```

From error message I think router ignores __NAMESPACE__. Maybe someone could help me find solution to my problem?

I have used https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool to create module and controllers.
My file structure is:

```
module/Admin
├── config
│   └── module.config.php
├── Module.php
├── src
│   └── Admin
│       └── Controller
│           ├── AnswersController.php
│           └── IndexController.php
└── view
    └── admin
        ├── answers
        │   └── index.phtml
        └── index
            └── index.phtml
```

My module.config.php:

```
return array(
    'controllers'  => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Admin\Controller\Answers' => 'Admin\Controller\AnswersController',
            'Admin\Controller\Index'   => 'Admin\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),
    'router'       => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'admin' => array(
                'type'          => 'literal',
                'options'       => array(
                    'route'    => '/admin',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes'  => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'       => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults'    => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

If I am changing: `'\__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',   'controller'    => 'Index',` to `'controller'    => 'Admin\Controller\Index'` I can access Index controller, but not Answers .

**Additional info:**

I found strange behavior of skeleton application. I have downloaded fresh skeleton application and this configuration works. If I am going to `localhost/application/index` or `localhost/application/answers` it works as accepted. But if I am changing Application module name to Admin and changing router configuration (replacing all application to admin and Application to Admin) and config stops working. Can anyone explain this? Maybe Application module works as default in skeleton applications?

I am using Zend Framework 2.2.4.

Comment: did you add namespace Admin\Controller; within your controller? And it would be helpful if you could name your file structure.

Comment: @cptnk Yes namespace was added by ZFTool. I have updated my question with file structure.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm still running into this in the year 2017. Thanks.

Comment: @HelloWorld I did not find the cause. We just wrote every route manually.

Answer (score 1):

add above default key

```
'answers' => array(
  'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
  'options' => array(
    'route'    => '/answers',

    'defaults' => array(
      'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Answers',
      'action'     => 'index',
    ),
  ),
),
```

if that not help try comment default key
So maybe try wildcards ?

```
'application' => array( 
    'type'    => 'segment', 
    'options' => array( 
        'route'    => '/[:controller][/:action][/:id]', 
        'constraints' => array(
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*', 
            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*', 
            'id'         => '[0-9]+', 
        ), 
        'defaults' => array( 
            'controller' => 'Application', 
            'action'     => 'index',
        ), 
    ), 
    'may_terminate' => true, 
    'child_routes' => array( 
        'default' => array( 
            'type'    => 'Wildcard', 
            'options' => array( 
            ), 
        ), 
    ), 
),
```

it's only lead not complete solution

Comment: I will use more controllers later. My goal is to determine controller from link

Comment: ok so maybe http://amber.localhost/admin/answers not http://amber.localhost/admin/Answers ?

Comment: Segments in that case are probably the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Set in Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not 100% sure of what you are trying to achieve but this may help you in a way. In case you have a variable controller param I would set up my routes like this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/admin[/:controller[/:action]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
     ),
```

When redirecting you would need to specify the controller and the action this way though.

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin', array('action' => 'newAction', 'controller' => 'someOtherController'));
```

URL View-Helper equivalent:

```
$this->url('admin', array('action' => 'newAction', 'controller' => 'someOtherController'));
```

EDIT:

Zend framework2 merges all config fiels trough your models and provides the Router Module with the array you have configured. In fact you could extend the Router class and alter it to your likeing.

As you can probably see it actually is not "mandatory" to provide the router with the namespace of each module within your config files. The router has your invoked Controllers and can "track" them via the zf2 naming convention.

EDIT2: I forgot to add some constraint's to the route can you try it with the updated route configuration again?

[image]

Comment: Same problem. No namespace. My goal is to get controller without manually writing routes to all controllers

Comment: You dont have to write the routes for each controller with the config I described. You'll just to add params to your redirecting. Lets asume you have a admin module, a user module and a application module. You now add a route to each Module. And within those configurations you just add a segment which "manages" your controllers and their actions.

Comment: I am getting same results. I can access default controller but not the other.

Comment: Still no namespace. Zend is still looking for Answer controller instead of Admin\Controller\Answer